# Sql Server 2012 for dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table named `Master` which contains a column `outtablename` that has data which are also table names having columns `score` and more. I want to fetch data from these tables dynamically.

`Master` table:

```
outtablename
==============
fte
wdp
```

and `fte` have data like below

`fte` table:

```
sku   score
=============
1        23
2        34
```

And I want to access data in `fte` dynamically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I have no idea what you are trying to ask.  Please post the full definition (CREATE TABLE script) of each of your tables, as well as some sample data from each.  Then, describe the relationship between those tables and post a sample of what you've tried to do and what you want the end product to look like.

Comment: Can you please give some example query?

Comment: Check out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026823/variable-table-name-using-dynamic-sql-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this query.

```
declare @outtablename varchar(256)
declare @STR Nvarchar(max)

declare tbl cursor
for select [outtablename] from Master

Open tbl
fetch next from tbl into @outtablename

while(@@fetch_status = 0)
begin 
   SET @STR ='select * from '+outtablename
   EXEC sp_executesql @STR 
   fetch next from tbl into @outtablename
end
close tbl
deallocate tbl
```