# C# MySQL Select from table where table name is a variable

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database with tables that are created by the user, this obviously means that I don't know what the tables are called before so I can't access them like others where I could simply do:

```
"SELECT FROM table_name"
```

To solve this the first method I tried was to use parameters like:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FROM @table");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", table_name);
```

However this caused an error, I presume this is because you can't use parameters for things like table names and column names.
The second way to solve this I had wad to just add the name of the table to the string:

```
string tableName = "table_name";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FROM " + tableName.ToString());
```

However as far as I'm aware this is very susceptible to attacks like SQL Injection. So my question is what is the best/safest way of accessing tables where the table name is a variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Some of the answers here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947736/sqlparameter-does-not-allows-table-name-other-options-without-sql-injection-at

Comment: soemthing like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14026823/81053

Comment: Thanks very much I shall try using a whitelist